# Calendar event problem

Tags: android

Actually i am get stuck in a big problem..I have created an app from which i can save event in my device calendar..Now when i save new events from my app in my device calendar it will always delete the events save previously by my app and save a new event and so on..so all works fine..now the big problem is that while deleting it will delete all the events of the calendar that are present in the device calendar including the events that are save by my app..so what i want is to delete only that event that are put by my app while inserting new event from my app not that are already present or which are directly assigned by me in device calendar..so can anyone please help me out to resolve this problem..the code i have use for inserting and deleting are..

```
    Resources res = c.getResources();

    Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "events");

    Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "reminders");

    ContentResolver cr = c.getContentResolver();

    Uri uri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(EVENTS_URI, 1);
    deleteEvent(cr, Resources res = c.getResources();

    Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "events");

    Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "reminders");

    ContentResolver cr = c.getContentResolver();

    //Deleting event from device calendar before saving new event
    deleteEvent(cr, EVENTS_URI, 1);

     //saving new data to calendar
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("calendar_id", 1);
    values.put("title", str);
    values.put("description", m_strDescription);                    
    values.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis()); 
    values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()); 
    values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
        Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);

    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
    values.put("method", 1);
    values.put("minutes", 10);
    cr.insert(REMINDERS_URI, values);
```

**Functions for deleting event**

```
private void deleteEvent(ContentResolver resolver, Uri eventsUri, int calendarId) 
{
    Cursor cursor;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) 
    { 
        cursor = resolver.query(eventsUri, new String[]{ "_id" }, "Calendars_id=" + calendarId, null, null);
    } 
    else 
    { 
        cursor = resolver.query(eventsUri, new String[]{ "_id" }, "calendar_id=" + calendarId, null, null);
    }
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        long eventId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        resolver.delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, eventId), null, null);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are using is deleting EVERY event: you need to save the ID of the event you create and only delete that one event. When you do this:

```
cr.insert(REMINDERS_URI, values);
```

change that to this:

```
Uri u = cr.insert(REMINDERS_URI, values);
```

This will save the URI of the event you create. You can then pass that URI into your `deleteEvent` method to only delete that one event, rather than all events.

Comment: but my delete function always call before inserting new event..i dont know how to proceed can you please do it for in my code..please it will really help me out

Comment: That means if i write Uri u = cr.insert(REMINDERS_URI, values), deleteEvent(cr,uri,values)..it gives me error that  values is not define.and it so because delete function is called before save